# prove that : if $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ : then : $a^2b^2(a^2+b^2-2)\geq (a^2+b^2)(ab-1)$

Tags: inequality, uvw

prove that : if $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ : then :

$$a^2b^2(a^2+b^2-2)\geq (a^2+b^2)(ab-1)$$

---

$$a^4b^2+b^4a^2-2a^2b^2 \geq a^3b-a^2b+b^2a-a^2$$

$$a^4b^2+b^4a^2-2a^2b^2 \geq a^3b-a^2+b^3a-b^2$$

now what ?

Comment: If I am not wrong, this question is taken from Turkish Junior Math Olympiad 2010. They also might have taken this from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ab=x$, $a^2+b^2=y$, then $0\leq 2x\leq y$ and we want
$$x^2(y-2)\geq y(x-1)$$
$$x^2y-2x^2\geq xy-y$$
$$y\geq\frac{2x^2}{x^2-x+1}$$

It is equivalent to show
$$2x\geq\frac{2x^2}{x^2-x+1}$$
$$x^2-x+1\geq x$$
$$(x-1)^2\geq0$$

Equality holds iff $a=b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

it is equivalent to $$(a-b)^2((ab)^2-ab+1)+2ab(ab-1)^2\geq 0$$ which is true.

Comment: Follows also by reflecting on my answer. I'm curious how you found it. Trial and error?

Comment: the trick is complete square

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+b=2u$ and $ab=v^2$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$v^4(4u^2-2v^2-2)\geq(4u^2-2v^2)(v^2-1)$$ or
$$v^4(2u^2-v^2-1)\geq(2u^2-v^2)(v^2-1)$$ or
$$2u^2v^4-v^6-v^4\geq2u^2(v^2-1)-v^4+v^2$$ or
$$2u^2(v^4-v^2+1)\geq v^6+v^2.$$
But $v^4-v^2+1>0$ and $u^2\geq v^2$ because it's just $(a-b)^2\geq0$.

Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$2v^2(v^4-v^2+1)\geq v^6+v^2,$$
which is
$$v^2(v^2-1)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: I can understand why it's equivalent $2u^2(v^4-v^2+1)\geq v^6+v^2$$?$